# The detail view accessory button on the call out on Annotations is not being displayed

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am a beginner in iOS development and am relatively new to Stack Overflow. The detail view accessory button on the call out on Annotations is not being displayed on the map.

```
PSPlaceMark *addAnnotation = [[PSPlaceMark alloc] initWithCoordinate:mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate] ;  
[addAnnotation setTitle:@"anshuk"];  
[addAnnotation setSubTitle:@"The pin subtitle goes here"]; 
MKPinAnnotationView *newAnnotation = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:addAnnotation reuseIdentifier:[addAnnotation title]] autorelease];
newAnnotation.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;
newAnnotation.animatesDrop = YES; 
newAnnotation.canShowCallout = YES;
newAnnotation.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
//newAnnotation.enabled = YES;

// Add a detail disclosure button to the callout.
UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
[rightButton addTarget:self action:@selector(self) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
newAnnotation.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;
```

this is the code and let me know where am i wrong.

Comment: Maybe you just didn't show it above, but you are doing nothing with you MKPinAnnotationView yet.

Another comment:
@selector(self) --> is your function `-(void)self;`? Then you are probably overriding something. Try @selector(pinClicked) and `-(void)pinClicked;` instead.

Comment: i have made changes to the (self) part.. thts not the issue right now.. detail disclosure button is not being displayed. it just shows the default callout without the button. whereas my newAnnotation is initwithannotation and newAnnotation.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;

Comment: Maybe stupid question, but are you sure newAnnotation is being displayed?